# what kind of vscode theme it is?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I was wathching online class and the theme which teacher was using looks so fine.
but I wasn't able to find it. Is there anyone know what kind of theme it is??

[image]

Comment: Hi Noah, SO is for programming questions. Your question will probably not be answered here. It will be answered [here: r/vscode](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/)

Comment: my 50c: Font looks pretty much like in this one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wesbos.theme-cobalt2 ("Operator Mono", otf+ttf can be googled).